# Capture/Log WCF Binding/Serialization/Deserialization Error

Tags: wcf, logging

I've class which has a set of attributes.
I'm trying to call WebService from custom Billing device (based on proprietary HW/SW). The problem is that in the application in some cases the required field (an integer in this case) is sent as null. WebService just rejects that.

Is there any way to log such errors in the Server as "return false" prompts the App to resend again (which will fail as the value is still null). Idea is to write to database the errors (with device details and the actual error, integer column is null in this case) and the Application/Web Admin can get in touch with user of the device to take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you can use Fiddler2 easily to capture any web traffic, including the full xml of a SOAP request/response (and it even handles SSL easily, unlike Wireshark)

For logging... I wish I knew. Sorry.

Also, dupe of In C#, [How to look at the actual SOAP request/response in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757990/how-to-look-at-the-actual-soap-request-response-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but our requirement is to log all the calls hitting the WebService error or no error.