# System.ServiceModel not found in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

I have a .NET Core xUnit project.  I'm trying to call a WCF service from it but get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An error occurred while loading attribute 'ServiceContractAttribute' on type 'IMyContract'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It works with a Framework 4.7 project with the same Nuget Package `System.ServiceModel.Http.4.3.0`.

Comment: @silkfire I feared that.  Has that been documented anywhere?  It's crazy that I can install the same package in different frameworks and get a different set of functionality.

Comment: @silkfire if that is _the answer_ than feel free to put it down.

Comment: See [Microsoft's .NET API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel?view=netcore-2.0) website for info on what's supported in .NET Core and what's .NET Framework only

Comment: @BanksySan Apparently it seems I was correct pertaining to the fact that it *has* been removed from the main framework itself; with that in mind, it was deeply unfortunate that I stated that there was no solution to this, when in fact Microsoft had made the relevant assemblies available on NuGet as optional packages instead. Feel free to change my accepted answer to the one with the most upvotes below.

Comment: or just run this in terminal window (dotnet add package System.ServiceModel.Primitives)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Microsoft has made available the relevant assemblies as packages on NuGet now.

**System.ServiceModel.Primitives** is the base package; add the others if necessary to your project.

[image]

**Update (April 28th, 2022)**:

WCF has been partially ported to .NET 5+ with an official library called *CoreWCF*: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/

Comment: "deprecated" -- do you have a reference for that? Per GitHub comments, it sounds like server-side WCF has not officially been deprecated: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1200

Comment: type 'IDispatchMessageInspector' and 'IServiceBehavior' not found in the  'System.ServiceModel'. any idea how to resolve _channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomInspectorBehavior());

Comment: For those wondering, as I did, why this answer has so many downvotes, it has been updated with completely different information.

Comment: Just as a note - System.ServiceModel has had continuous porting updates since .NET Core 2.0, includes the new .NET 5.0 framework (the NETSTANDARD one, not ASP.NET)

Comment: "add the others if necessary to your project" - System.ServiceModel.Http.

Answer (score 99):

If you are using `.NET Standard 2.0` (that's what I tested with), you can install compatible `NuGet` packages.

The basic service model is available in **`System.ServiceModel.Primitives`** (currently v4.4.0).

If required, install `System.ServiceModel.Http` as well.

Comment: Thanks! I solver my issue by installer servicemodel.primitives package

Comment: When adding those references while using `netcoreapp2.0`. The following error gets thrown: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Configuration files are not supported.`.

Comment: A library of mine has "System.ServiceModel.Http" and works when directly integrated. When I add it as Nuget package, I also need to add "System.ServiceModel.Http" to my actual project -_-     .

Answer (score 20):

The [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) wraps SvcUtil.exe and will generate a .NET Standard project from your endpoint. Look in the project file and you'll see the ServiceModel references that will work for you.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I needed to do this I was able to use the generated class library in my .NET Core project.

Comment: Good thinking!  I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks to [CWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652105/cwagner) the link has been updated.

Comment: Or, `dotnet svcutil` if you want command line control: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, i had to add .asmx web service into my class library asp.net core project, i tried to add reference directly by add connected service option but i wan unable to see any config file and lots of references errors also, below are the steps by which i solve my problem.

1-Create library project name Service Mapping
2-Create folder Web References and then create inside folder ClientHotel
3-Open terminal in visual studio from view --->   terminal --- command prompt.
4-Integrate asmx service by command
svcutil   http://abctest.asmx (.asmx URL)
inside  inside ClientHotel folder.

5-it will create .cs class and output.config file with references in it.
6-Now i had errors of references like
the type or namespace servicecontractattribute does not exist in namespace System.ServiceModel etc.

7-Install Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives
Then all references errors will be gone.

That is how i was able to add .asmx service to my class library project.