# WCF in .net core (TransportWithMessageCredential)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I try to create a connection to a WCF client in dotnet core 2.0, I receive an platform unsupported error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'The value 'TransportWithMessageCredential' is not supported in this context for the binding security property 'securityMode'.'
```

If I remove the `BasicHttpSecurityMode`, I receive an argument exception:
    System.ArgumentException: 'The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.'

Code:

```
ChannelFactory<BlackBoxContract> factory = null;
BlackBoxContract serviceProxy = null;
Binding binding = null;

binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);

factory = new ChannelFactory<BlackBoxContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https:......."));;
serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Anyone that found a workaround as this might be on the long term roadmap?
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/8

Comment: Can the WCF client code go into a class library that targets .NET Standard? Then you could call the library from .NET Core. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550508/444244) may be relevant.

Comment: Are you using the WCF connected services? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService

Comment: The WCF connected services is giving me an error, for the same reason somewhere. Not supported, the error message is just slightly different..
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1274

Comment: @Boggin I generated the service already, it's the connection to that is giving the error.

Comment: someone found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found a valid workaround, there is a package you can use for this:
https://github.com/gravity00/SimpleSOAPClient

```
using SimpleSOAPClient;
using SimpleSOAPClient.Handlers;
using SimpleSOAPClient.Helpers;
using SimpleSOAPClient.Models;
using SimpleSOAPClient.Models.Headers;

...

_client = SoapClient.Prepare().WithHandler(new DelegatingSoapHandler());
_client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
_client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "Action...");

 var requestEnvelope = SoapEnvelope
     .Prepare()
     .Body(request)
     .WithHeaders(KnownHeader.Oasis.Security.UsernameTokenAndPasswordText(Username, Password));

var responseEnvelope = _client.Send(Url, "CanNotBeEmpty", requestEnvelope);
```

Got it to work like this, as a charm...

Comment: What is that "SOAPAction" and "Action..." . No idea what to write! Help?

Comment: This is not a bad sln but most soap services will require the body encoding with an xml namespace. So bear this in mind.

Comment: The original author has a work around to solve the xml ns issue. After 2 days of fighting with it, I have been able to get something working now.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz how did you manage to solve the namespaces issue?

Comment: Sorry no - had to abandon it, OP's sln was too flakey in the end. Could not reliably deserialise soap msg with DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 13):

This has been fixed by the latest packages.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This crucial point saved my life. I was working with 4.4.0 but it never worked. With 4.6.0 version I have solved my problem. Besides, you can use seperate assembly in .net framework and can use in .net core

Comment: Best answer in 2020