# target .net framework class library with System.ServiceModel dependency from a .net core application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0, .net-4.6.2

It should be possible to reference .net framework class libraries from .net core 2 projects in Visual Studio 2017 but I get a runtime exception when trying reference a class library dependent System.ServiceModel.

Create a “Console App (.NET Core)”. Visual studio set target framework to ".NET Core 2.0".

Create a “Class Library (.Net Framework)”. Visual studio set target framework to ".NET Framework 4.6.1".

Reference “System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0” from the class library.
Fill Class1 in the class library with the following:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("");
    }
}
```

Reference the class library from the console app.
From the main method of the console app call the test method in Class1:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Class1().Test();
    }
}
```

Build and run. An exception is thrown then the `Test()` method is tried executed:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred   HResult=0x80070002
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.   Source=   StackTrace:    at ClassLibrary1.Class1.Test()
>   in c:\users\rth\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs:line
>   15    at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\users\rth\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 11

System.ServiceModel is not in the /bin/Debug folder of either project.

I have tried to manually copy the System.ServiceModel to the /bin/debug folder of the console app but get the same error.

How do I reference a class library that reference System.ServiceModel without getting runtime exceptions?

Comment: System.ServiceModel is in the GAC, and the Framework directory, at least on my machine.  You may have referenced an assembly with a specific version requirement that you are not meeting.  Check your GAC, and your framework directories.  Then check to make sure your reference isn't targeted as a specific version.

Comment: @Kevin-hirst: When I look at properties for the reference to System.ServiceModel then path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.ServiceModel.dll. If I take this file and place it under /bin/debug in the console app then it still doesn’t work and the assembly loader are supposed to look here.

One thing to notice: there is no problem if I create a .net framework console app (not .net core) and reference the same class library.

Comment: If I change the target framework of the console app to .NET Framework 4.6.1 the it works.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code above working without the exception:

1. Update your `Class Library (.Net Framework)` to `Class Library (.NET Standard 2.0)`
2. Add NuGet package `System.ServiceModel.Http (version v4.4.0)` to `Class Library (.NET Standard 2.0)` dependencies.

Comment: Yes .NET Standard 2.0 libraries can be referenced just fine. I however need to reference Sys-tem.ServiceModel version 4.0.0.0 specifically because version 4.4.0 of System.ServiceModel.* does not contain the functionality I need: NetTcpSecurity with SecurityMode.Message and MessageCredentialType.Windows. Sorry for not being crystal clear on this. I have added the specific version number to the question.

Comment: @Rolf you might want to check if this this workaround with `SimpleSOAPClient` does the trick you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/45988249/804385

Comment: The basic service model is available in `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` NuGet package, which is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0