# How to create a 'Binding' in asp net core 2.0?

Tags: data-binding, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a Binding, but everytime that I do, it gives me errors about

> NotSupportedException: The value 'TransportWithMessageCredential' is not supported in this context for the binding security property 'Mode'.
>      at System.ServiceModel.HttpBindingBase.CheckSettings()

Here's my code:

```
    Binding CreateBinding()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        var elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
        elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
        return new CustomBinding(elements);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... [WCF in .net core (TransportWithMessageCredential)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567598/wcf-in-net-core-transportwithmessagecredential#45600114)

Comment: It isn't compatible at all with Asp Net Core 2.0