# .NET Core Soap PlatformNotSupportedException, cant create custom binding

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, soap, basic-authentication

I am trying to get data from SOAP service but cant get it work. The problem is, I think .net core has not been implemented all of the binding methods. I also have working example but it is written with .net Framework.

So question is, 
Here is the working configuration "Web.config"

```
</customBinding>
    <binding name="example">
  <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" includeTimestamp="false" />
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
  <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

I attempted to do that configuration in .net core, but no way. Always get some platform error and even If I get it work, service needs basic authentication and it fail etc etc. 
So here is my latest attempt which give me "TransportSecurityBindingElement.BuildChannelFactoryCore is not supported." error:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding()
            {
                Name = "example",
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 100, 0, 0),
                SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 100, 0, 0),
            };
            var element1 = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            var element2 = new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
            {
                ManualAddressing = false,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                AllowCookies = false,
                AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
                UseDefaultWebProxy = true
            };
            var element3 = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            binding.Elements.Add(element1);
            binding.Elements.Add(element3);
            binding.Elements.Add(element2);
```

And also, As you can see, I need a security binding which needs

```
<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" includeTimestamp="false" />
```

But even in code, I cannot create that binding on my own. Even If I did, code will not work because of the problem as I mentioned above.
Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't suppose you ever solved this issue? Experiencing it right now in core 3.1

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1257

Comment: Actually it is solved via creating a custom security header and bind it.

Comment: In addition to the comment of @OzanTürkerDemir I had to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567598/wcf-in-net-core-transportwithmessagecredential/59136093#59136093