# ServiceBehaviorAttribute not exist in the namespace System.ServiceModel

Tags: .net, .net-core, dll, frameworks, migration

I am trying to migrate from .Net Framework to .Net Core.
I added System.ServiceModel.Primitives nuget package, even though I am getting below issue.

Issue - ServiceBehaviorAttribute not exist in the namespace System.ServiceModel

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545013/system-servicemodel-not-found-in-net-core-project

Comment: I already added System.ServiceModel.Primitives but in that ServiceBehaviourAttribute is not there.

Comment: @sameeraguntimadugu, any luck with this? I'm experiencing that same issue upgrading WPF from net48 to net6...

Comment: I have removed the lines related to ServiceBehaviorAttribute. @BozhidarStoyneff

Comment: So, no luck on having an alternative anywhere?