# How to use IErrorHandler and IServiceBehavior .Net Standard 2.1

Tags: wcf, .net-standard-2.1, iservicebehaviors

How can I use IErrorHandler and IServiceBehavior in a .NET Standard 2.1 project?
I tried to add the nuget System.ServiceModel.Primitives but still doesn't work, and I also can't find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: You also need to install `System.ServiceModel.Http` package,https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112592/17218587, and you can download other packages as needed.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation

Comment: @LanHuang Even after I installed all packages: (System.ServiceModel.Duplex, System.ServiceModel.Federation, System.ServiceModel.Http, System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, System.ServiceModel.Primitives, System.ServiceModel.Security) it still can't find

Comment: You also need to add a reference to the project, you can right click on the project, go to "**Add Connected Service**" and click "**Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider**", you can also take a look at [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide).