# Generate .Net Core Soap Webservices Proxy in MacOS

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, proxy, .net-core

I have seen a c# tutorial where the instructor generates the proxy using

> "Add reference "

(but he was using windows pc )

I am using a mac and I am struggling generate the proxy of a web-service with the same approach, It generates files with

> system.Web.Services

a package which isn't existing in the .Net Core

I did many researches and I found that isn't included in the .Net Core, i try to add it as an externally but didn't succeed, 
I read some articles telling that there is an alternative called WCF, but again I didn't found it on mac, all tutorials or official documentation uses windows, I've seen that is working with a .exe which make me sure, this hell isn't existing on mac or other linux systems !

Some can help ? any ideas ? alternatives ? shortcuts ?

Thank you to read it until here !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was based on  using .Net Core CLI as in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide)

1. Create a directory named HelloSvcutil for your project and make it your current directory, as in the following example:

> mkdir HelloSvcutil
>
> cd HelloSvcutil

2. Create a new C# console project in that directory using the dotnet new command as follows:

> dotnet new console

3. Open the HelloSvcutil.csproj project file in your editor, edit the Project element, and add the [dotnet-svcutil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-svcutil) NuGet package as a CLI tool reference, using the following code:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-svcutil" Version="1.0.*" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
4. Restore the dotnet-svcutil package using the dotnet restore command as follows:

> dotnet restore

5. Run dotnet with the svcutil command to generate the web service reference file as follows: (use your web-service link, in my case : http://localhost.com/BanqueWS?wsdl )

> dotnet svcutil http://contoso.com/SayHello.svc

he generated file is saved as HelloSvcutil/ServiceReference1/Reference.cs. The dotnet_svcutil tool also adds to the project the appropriate WCF packages required by the proxy code as package references.

6. Restore the WCF packages using the dotnet restore command as follows:

> dotnet restore

7. Open the Program.cs file in your editor, edit the Main() method, and replace the auto-generated code with the following code to invoke the web service:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var client = new SayHelloClient();
      Console.WriteLine(client.HelloAsync("dotnet-svcutil").Result);
   }
   ```
8. Run the application using the dotnet run command as follows:

> dotnet run

Answer (score 1):

You could try to install [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService) for VS 2017. You could follow the part “how to use the extension” to generate the client code, then copy and paste the generated code to your VS Code project.

Dot Net core is all about rest, not SOAP

Answer (score 1):

As adding [`Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) does not work for `ASP.NET Core 2.1` project [at the moment](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5703), you can add new `.NET Standard` `class library` project targeted to `Standard 2.0` and add service reference to it:

1. Right click on project
2. Select `Add -> Connected Service`
3. In `Connected Services` window select `Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider`
4. Specify `WSDL` details as described the the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)
5. Add new library reference to your `ASP.NET Core` web application (targeted to `.NET Core 2.1`)

Comment: Is it valid on mac ?

Comment: There is no Add -> Connected Service on Mac

Comment: @NikolayKlimchuk try shaman dance - check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496773/how-to-reference-a-wsdl-file-using-visual-studio-code