# Tesseract OCR wrapper for net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ocr, tesseract

Im searching for a Tesseract OCR wrapper for net core; actualy, when i add the nuget Tesseract package get the warning:

```
Package 'Tesseract 3.0.2' was restored using 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework 
'.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible 
with your project.
```

Any help? Is there an alternative that works well?

Comment: Consider to add issue here - [github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues)

Comment: What way are you referencing the package? Directly to `.NET Core` project or via `Standard` library? [Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469383/804385) you need to add external dependencies to `Standard` library and then reference you library in your `.NET Core` project.

Comment: @DmitryPavlov i think that is directly; im doing this: `dotnet add package Tesseract --version 3.2.0-alpha4`

Answer (score 2):

The new version supports NetStandard 2.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/

Comment: Prerelease version uses Tesseract 4, which is a lot better than 3.