# I need to create a .Net Web API project that my .Net Core project can connect to, but I'm on a Mac

Tags: c#, windows, macos, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Angular/.NetCoreWebApi app running in Visual Studio Code on my Mac and I need to run some older WCF/SOAP calls. I can't do this with .Net Core (doesn't support WCP/Soap protocols) so I was told the best solution is to create a .Net Web API project and have my .Net Core project call it to make the web service calls.

I'm on a Mac! So is this even possible knowing that .Net doesn't run on a Mac??
If I can create a project to make these calls on my Mac, which project type do I select to create in the terminal/command prompt, when doing a >dotnet new -h?

If what I want isn't possible, is it possible to run the .Net app inside a docker on my Mac?

If these are all a **NO** I can use my windows machine at work instead, but I'm looking at the types of projects to create on my Win machine on the command prompt and I still don't see a .Net Web Api app. Only .Net Core projects. I have the .Net framework 4.8 packages installed! And I can create the .Net project in Visual Studio, so is this the only way to create it?

[image]

Comment: I'm on a Mac! -> which supports Hypervisor and installation of windows in it. Case closed.

Comment: When you say hypervisor. You mean a VM?

Comment: Sure, a VM is possible. You could also look into Mono.

Comment: ya a VM would work, but my Mac is a 2013 Air and not that powerful. I had a VM on it a few years agao and it lags big time running a Win 10 VM

Comment: There's also the Bootcamp option.

Comment: true, forgot about that option. Hate the switching between the two though. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

[.Net Core supports WCF clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide), so there shouldn't be any reason for you not to use the ASP.NET Core Web API project type, assuming you mean you need to call a WCF service external to your project as a client, and not to **host** a WCF service.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478969/313414) showed that it was possible by manually adding and invoking the svcutil tool.

Comment: Hi Tom. The later, my application needs to call a WCF service external to my project. What's funny, and maybe you can answer this, is my app is calling multiple WCF web services. I can generate the web service proxy files with svcutil and one of them works to one service, but the second one doesn't. They are to two different clients. Is it possible that one supports the proxy file I generated with .Net Core and the other doesn't? I'm not sure how they configure things on their(server) end!

Comment: @user1186050 If it doesn't work for one, sounds like that should be a separate question, with its own description of the steps you did and what the result was.

Comment: @user1186050 it's fairly established at this point that there is a good portion of the gamut of SOAP standards that svcutil doesn't understand, in particular <policy> expressions it tends to ignore, in my experience. WCF supports the vast majority of possible configurations expressible in a WSDL but you'd have to know how to configure them and the proxy generation won't do it for you. As mentioned in a prior comment, that is not generally answerable without some specifics.