# how to get the xml representation of the SOAP request message?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the WSDL of a SOAP web service and I am consuming it via my MVC application.

From adding the WSDL as a web service to my Visual Studio solution it automatically creates a proxy class for me and it handles all the serialization/destabilization for me which is really awesome for a while. I have been using this proxy class to call/send my SOAP request to the web service (with pure c# code and no XML involves) and I got my response message back and everything is working great.

However, there is a need now for me to find what is the exact xml representation of the SOAP message that I am sending to the web service. How can I get/find/make this?

Comment: You can always trace and write a SOAP request/response. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461744/get-soap-message-before-sending-it-to-the-webservice-in-net. If you only wish to check and not log or write it, I would recommend use Fiddler.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
var serxml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(request.GetType());
var ms = new MemoryStream();
serxml.Serialize(ms, request);
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

where xml is your raw SOAP

Comment: What is "request" ?

Comment: An answer from many years ago, but this was a big help and just what I needed today. Thanks.