# How to get XMLResponse from Webservice in c# Soap or other soap

Tags: c#, soap, web-services

I want to integrate with webservice writes in php (PEAR SOAP).

Wsdl file is without types definition.

When i was connect to webservice i getting a null response.

In WebServiceStudio i see xmlrequest and xmlresponse, my I get xmlresponse in c# default soap or other soap.

I know what is causing the null response. PEAR SOAP returnx STRUCT[X] as a response type, where X is number of list element.

When I my get XMLresponse and replace this section then it would be cool

Regards

Sorry for my english

Comment: Duplicate,methinks. Check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256234/how-do-i-get-access-to-soap-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you need is [`getLastResponse()`](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP/docs/0.12.0/SOAP/SOAP_Client.html#methodgetLastResponse), but if it's anything like other, similar HTTP-stream classes, you'll probably need to set a flag to enable capturing the raw requests/responses. Then again, maybe not, since you apparently have to use `parseResposne` to get the data out of the XML.

Try:

```
$soapClient->call(some,parameters,here);
$response = $soapClient->getLastResponse();

echo $response;
```

Comment: but i want get xmlresponse in c#. I write c# client for php webservice server, which i can't change. I must do everything on my side (on client side)

Comment: Oh, I got confused. I thought you were saying you could see what was happening by using C#, but couldn't get the raw XML in PHP. You should consider simplifying your question to "how can I access the raw XML response with C# SOAP library?" If you can't change the server, it's not really relevant to go into such detail about it.

Comment: Actually, someone has asked, and there is a very clear solution at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256234/how-do-i-get-access-to-soap-response